# SSL DSN hidden redirect from sub1.domain1.com to sub2.domain2.com

Tags: redirect, https, ssl-certificate

I need to do a setup, where users would be able to access URL sub1.domain1.com that would be mapped by DSN to sub2.domain2.com, so all further communication would appear to be with sub1.domain1.com, however in reality it would just be "redirected" to sub2.domain2.com. HTTPS is required too, so simple CNAME wouldn't do it.

So far I have found out about SAN certificate. With that certificate it seems like it would be possible to accomplish this. However it has one drawback for me - with every new domain that is added to this certificate, all other domain owners must confirm this. And this is not very suitable for my case, because I expect new domains to be added on regular basis.

All domains would point to one certain subdomain (for example: sub1.domain1.com -> sub2.domain2.com,sub3.domain3.com ->sub2.domain2.com, sub4.domain4.com->sub2.domain2.com ..), so the certificate doesn't have to allow redirection between all domains mutually, but it would be enough to allow redirection from all domains to one certain domain (sub2.domain2.com)

Are there more suitable alternatives to accomplish this?

Comment: When user types `https://sub4.domain4.com` in their browser's address bar, do you want (when the page is displayed) address in the bar to change to `https://sub2.domain2.com`?

Comment: nono, I want user to see always only https://sub4.domain4.com

Comment: DNS QUESTIONS MUST BE PROGRAMMING RELATED. Use this tag for programming questions related to writing code that interacts with the Domain Name System (DNS); for example, writing code that uses gethostbyname()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, when user types https://sub4.domain4.com in their browser's address bar,  you don't want (when the page is displayed) address in the bar to change to https://sub2.domain2.com then technically there is no HTTP redirection involved. You just have one website/webapp which is reachable via multiple hostnames (which is nothing unusual).

You need

1. CNAMEs to be in place
2. If you can't get (or it is complicated to maintain - which is expected, especially if you do not own the domains) one SSL/TLS cert with all hostnames, then you can always configure your webserver with multiple virtual hosts, each with their own certificate, and keep adding virtual hosts as needed. All virtual hosts can be configured to serve the same content (or just reverse proxy requests to the same one webapp running behind the proxy). Technical implementation depends on the platform used, but is typically not complicated.

Comment: hmmm, but in this case, would I have to "ask" the domain owners for their private keys to their certificates?

Comment: Not necessarily. After they CNAME their sub4.domain4.com to your hostname, you should be able to create the cert (for their hostname) yourself, for example using certbot.

Comment: oh right, a domain doesn't have to have only one valid certificate. so they can keep their current certificate and I can generate completely new one just for their subdomain (sub4.domain4.com) that I will set to my virtual host. I was scared about the CNAME, but at the end of the day its just one more step before actual IP resolution, so the certificate of landing domain (sub2.domain2.com) is not important at all. right?

Comment: If none of the users will directly be using that hostname in browser address bar (and no web page assets urls are referring to that hostname), then you don't need that cert. In fact, that is not a landing domain at all then, it is just used as one substep in DNS resolving

Comment: Yes, that's making it clear now. So it's really basic and easy stuff after all. Thank you.